# WebKit - what does it do?

Tags: webkit

Tell me please, the only thing I understand at the moment is that WebKit is a C ++ library, which somehow, if I understand correctly, takes a full-fledged HTML page as input and somehow renders / renders it ??

And if Javacscript, Jquery and Ajax are used in HTML, does the library also process them itself or what? And does ajax initiate itself?

If it’s not difficult, tell me, are there any simple examples / lessons where one could start in order to understand how WebKit works and what it does?

PS: Is it possible to use WebKit for parsing sites?

Answer (score 0):

WebKit is a web browser engine. It is my understanding that yes, it also processes Javascript inside the HTML as that is part of what a web browser engine does.  You can read more at Webkit's homepage: https://webkit.org/

Comment: thanks, but can you tell me if there are examples of using WebKit? On their site I did not find anything like that, only a description of the functions.

Comment: Did you check the "getting started" section? There's a link to it right there on the homepage.  It seems there are some tools you need to set up before getting the webkit code to work. Webkit is a very complex project. The only way to understand how it works is to read its source code which could take you a long time.

Comment: This I saw - this is building a library. But I want to understand where i can see how the WebKit API is used. That is, examples of using the API function webkit. These are the ones I can't find.